# jQuery inArray() function not working with dynamic generated array, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am just using inArray() function in jquery but its not working. Actually I want check value in an array. I got lots of solutions on stackoverflow but nothing working that's why I created new post.

There is an hours format 1-24 and user can select their time slot like 1-3, 5-9, etc..

here is my code

```
jQuery('.select_hours').click(function(){ 
            var favorite = new Array();
            jQuery.each(jQuery("input[name='hour_count']:checked"), function(){            
                favorite.push(jQuery(this).val());
            });

            console.log(favorite);

            var max_v = Math.max.apply(Math,favorite);
            var min_v = Math.min.apply(Math,favorite);

            // check the number sequence
            for(var i = min_v; i <= max_v; i++){

                if(jQuery.inArray(i,favorite) != -1){
                    alert('Hours in sequence!');
                }else{
                    alert('Please select hours in sequence!');
                }
            }

        });
```

Please help me in this..

Here is the HTML checkboxes and button:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="hour_count" id="hour_count_1" value="1"><input type="checkbox" name="hour_count" id="hour_count_2" value="2"><input type="checkbox" name="hour_count" id="hour_count_3" value="3"><button type="button" id="select_hours" class="select_hours">Select Hours</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `val()` on a checkbox returns a string containing the set value of the checkbox. But your `for` loop requires `number`s. That's why you need to push `number`s, not `string`s into your array. Use

```
favorite.push(parseInt(jQuery(this).val()));
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/f2kgetec/

Comment: Thank you so much @Andrei, you save me. I just spoiled my whole day for this silly mistake.

Comment: You're welcome, @ManishNegi. And it's not a silly mistake. It's a common one, which you'll learn to avoid. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

The `inArray` method uses a strict comparison.
Maybe the issue is just that you are comparing strings and numbers.
Try to convert the max_v and minx_v to strings int his way:

```
var max_v = "" + Math.max.apply(Math,favorite);
var min_v = "" + Math.min.apply(Math,favorite);
```

And then in the `for` uses a `parseInt(min_v) parseInt(max_v)` for cycling.

p.s. Updating as per comment, you can of course also parse directly the `.val()`

Cleaner solution would be to use an array of numbers directly converting the `.val()`

```
favorite.push(parseInt(jQuery(this).val()))
```

Then if you want to look for an element inside the array, just use standard `indexOf` method

```
if (favorite.indexOf(myValueToCheck !== -1))
```

Comment: A better way would be to parseInt on `.val()`s. But, as a rule of thumb, you should not make assumptions when answering. It is best you do not answer a question that does not provide sufficient information about the source of the problem.

Comment: Yeah, sure you can directly convert to int the .val().
About answering, I think there are enough info about. The problem should be the comparison between strings and numbers.
And you posted the answer as well highlighting this issue :)

Comment: Yes, after testing, I realized `checkbox`'s `.val()` always returns a `string` and a `for` loop always requires integers. However, both existing answers suggested pushing strings into the array and subsequently parsing them to ints, rather than pushing ints to the array, which is much cleaner.

Comment: To be honest the cleaner solution is to use array of numbers and use a simple indexOf for finding if the element is in.

Comment: There are several ways to do it and whether one is better than the other is clearly debatable. But considering the current code, the easiest fix, IMHO, is the one I proposed. Of course, one could go about and streamline the entire script above into a `one-liner` but, most probably, that would cease to be an answer about `inArray()` :).

Comment: yep, even the need to get min and max spending time for cycling two times inside the array doesn't make really sense. 
You can just use an indexOf inside the first array avoiding the two loops for getting max and min :)

Comment: `$('.select_hours').on('click',function(){ $('input[name="hour_count"]:checked').map(function(){alert($(this).val()+' hours in sequence')})});` Cleaner, faster. No array, no parsing. Just functionality.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery.inArray returns the index of the element if found or -1 if it isn't -- not a boolean value. So the correct is

```
if(jQuery.inArray(i, favorite) !== -1)
{
     console.log("is in array");
     alert('Hours in sequence!');
}
 else {
    console.log("is NOT in array");
    alert('Please select hours in sequence!');
}
```